# convergence of discrete random variables with finite entropy

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let $Z$ be the set of discrete random variables on some probability space. Define the quantity $d(X_1,X_2)=h(X_1 \mid X_2)+h(X_2 \mid X_1)$ between two random variables $X_1, X_2 \in Z$. For $X \in Z$ and $X_n \in Z$, is there a link between $\Pr(X_n \neq X) \to 0$ and $d(X_n,X) \to 0$ ?

Comment: If the alphabet is finite, you can get what you want (at least an implication of the form $P(X_n \neq X) \rightarrow 0 \implies d(X_n,X) \rightarrow 0$) using Fano's inequality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano's_inequality

Comment: Yes I was aware of this fact when asking my question. Maybe I should had included this note in my question.

Comment: So you are looking for the backward direction?

Comment: The backward direction and the infinite case with finite entropy.

Comment: Cool problem :)

Comment: I think the backward case can also be handled "by hand," but all of these will not work for the infinite case of course. Maybe you should also think about constructing a counterexample.

Comment: Yes and looking carefully at the proof of Fano's equality could help to find a counterexample.

Comment: There is a generalization of Fano's to countably infinite alphabets: Han and Verdu, "Generalizing the Fano Inequality." Hopefully you have access to ieeexplore.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Since $H(X_n) \leq H(X) + H(X_n\mid X)$, one should simply search an example where $H(X_n)$ does not go to $H(X)$. But it's time to sleep for me now.